# I want to change the p-calender border when touched and invalid

Tags: sass

I want to change the p-calendar border when touched and invalid. As an example when the user clicks on the calendar and didn't input any value then the calendar border should change to the red color. I'm doing this because there is an error with the border right side.

I have already created a code for the border and border color. Please help me to change the calendar border color when the calendar is touched and invalid.

### SCSS

```
:host ::ng-deep .overtime-log-form {
  .col-12 {
    padding: 0;
  }
  &-working-hours {
    display: flex;
    .field {
      &:first-child {
        margin-right: 2.0625rem;
      }
      .p-calendar {
        max-width: 81px;
        border:solid #e7e7e7 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      //red border when touched and invalid value
      p-calendar.ng-touched.ng-invalid{
        max-width: 81px;
        border:solid #ac2525 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
  #reason {
    min-height: 7.6rem;
    max-height: 7.6rem;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you get the answer. i need solution too

Answer (score 0):

hi damith i cant very understand your question but understand you like to hover mouse on border border change color to red i think you can use the border:hover to style your tag but i don no the code is run or bug can you read the document to solve the problem ok have nice day bye

Comment: Hi @reza_box2002! I want to change the p-calendar border color when the input invalid